# subtracting letters in c

Tags: c, subtraction, letters-and-numbers

**I would like to know how to "subtract letters" in C:**
I mean, I have 2 letters, 'a' and 'c' and i want to execute 'c'-'a'='b' which is 3-1=2.
How is it possible to obtain the same behaviour in C?
I can conversion *Letters->Numbers* but how to manage the *limited lenght* of the alphabet? **Thank you.**

Comment: Thanks for the answers, what I needed exactly was managing the fact that alphabet has 26 letters. I mean, doing as you suggest I couldn't do b-z or b-d for example.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be when calculating `'b'-'z'`?

Comment: 'b' - 'z' == 'c', twain249 perfectly understood, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can treat the letters as numbers and then add the letter `'a'` back to normalize it

so

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'c';
int diff = c2 - c1; //'c' - 'a' = 2
char ans = diff + 'a' - 1; //add 'a' and subtract 1 to normalize it
```

If you want the number difference just use `diff` from my answer (`ans` will give you the letter).

This will not wrap around so

```
'a' - 'b'
```

will result in `-1` (or the character before a)

If you want to handle negatives with a wrap you have to check it

```
int diff = c2 - c1;
char ans;
diff > 0 ? ans = diff + 'a' - 1 : 'z' + diff + 1;
```

This will give:

1. `'z'` for `'b'-'c'`
2. `'y'` for `'b'-'d'`

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `%` operator for this? `-2 % 26 = 24`, which is what you'd get with your algorithm anyway.

Comment: @SashaChedygov What's the point with that? It would only make the code slower and harder to read.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for and couldn't find; but what's z, did you mean 'z'?

Comment: I meant 'z', what do you get for 'b'-'c'?

Comment: I think `%` is way easier on the eyes, but to each his own I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking this?

```
char a1,a2,a3;
a3 = a1 - a2 + 'a';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I needed exactly was managing the fact that alphabet has 26 letters. I mean, doing as you suggest I couldn't do b-z or b-d for example.

Comment: in C language. the 'a' ~ 'z' is represented to number, so you can do it like the integer. so the b - d = -2.

Comment: Just have in mind that the signedness of the char type is implementation-defined. This code is non-portable and will possibly cause undefined behavior because of integer underflow. For example `a3 = 'a' - 'b' + 'a'` is undefined behavior on implementations where the char type is unsigned.

Comment: @Lundin The char is implementation-defined but it is not to say the calculation of char is implementation-defined. First, the compiler promotes the char to int to calculate the expression. Second, in C99 standard 6.2.5, it said "If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be positive."

Comment: @RolandXu The integer -1 is not a member of any known character set, so there are no guarantees. The main problem here is that the characters are promoted to int, which is guaranteed to be signed. But then the result is stuffed back into a char again. Had the result been stored in an int and not a char, the code would be safe.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, if the value cross the range of character, the result is undefined. But value, int type, of expression is well defined. if the value map in the range of character, the result is also well defined.